# nativeAudio not reset on livereload

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I load a background music with Ionic Native Audio plugin, and work with the app with --livereload flag (ionic cordova run android --livereload) and first time I run everything is fine, but if I made some changes in the code and save them, then I got the following console message:

> "A reference already exists for the specified audio id."

As I see the problem is, the audio not rested when the ionic recompile the code after it changed.

This is the code inside the AppComponent constructor:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    statusBar.hide();
    splashScreen.hide();

    self.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('bgMusic', 'assets/sounds/bg-music.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then(() => {
        console.log('success');

        self.nativeAudio.play('bgMusic', () => console.log('bgMusic is done playing'));
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });   
});
```

I tried to unload the audio in the ngOnDestroy method but I think that is not called in Ionic.

Is there any solution to prevent this, and reset the sound after every code change?